# How can I get the activation value of each hidden layers of an ANN

Tags: python, theano, keras

I have an ANN model and i am trying to get the activation values of all the hidden layers. I have trained the network with a 90dim matrix and i have 1 hidden layers which is 150dim. My model structure is one 90dim input layer, one hidden layer of 150dim and  one output of 90dim. I have trained and tested the data. After that i m using the .predict() function to predict output using my test dataset. I am feeding the predicted output as the next input and so on. Now i want to get the activation value of the hidden layers of the predict function. I am using the following code to achieve it but its not working:

```
write_predict_data = pd.ExcelWriter("/home/workstation/ANN/prediction_data_2.xlsx",engine="xlsxwriter")

write_activations_data = pd.ExcelWriter("/home/rianzaman/Downloads/activition_of_hidden_node_2.xlsx",engine="xlsxwriter")

for i in range(0, 200):
    print("Predicting ...",)
    next_prediction = my_model.predict(X_test, 1,)
    output_file_data = pd.DataFrame(next_prediction)
    output_file_data.to_excel(write_predict_data, sheet_name='Sheet1')

    #To get activation

    get_activations = theano.function([my_model.layers[0].input], my_model.layers[1].get_output(train=False),
                                      allow_input_downcast=True)
    activations = get_activations(next_prediction)
    output_file_data_activation = pd.DataFrame(activations)
    output_file_data_activation.to_excel(write_activations_data, sheet_name='Sheet1')

X_test = next_prediction
write_predict_data.save()
```

When i m running the code i m getting a 90dim output which basically i think is the output layers dataset.
Can anybody tell me what's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_activations(next_prediction)` should be `get_activations(X_test)` - you want to pass inputs to `get_activations`, not labels.

Comment: well i have used "X_test" and it seems that it's also not working. I m not getting the hidden layers data, instead i m getting the output layer data. As i m writing the data of the predict function as well as the activation function the outputs are just identical of both functions.

Comment: You probably want `my_model.layers[0].get_output(train=False)` instead of `my_model.layers[1].get_output(train=False)` also?